# Using HTTP Vary header to decide on a strategy to process a request

Tags: http, rest, api-design

I have a specific REST endpoint that creates a topic in a forum; but I want to apply different strategies when processing the request. e.g. If client A makes the call, perform moderation. if client B makes the call, do something else. The easiest would be to add a query param for differentiation:

```
 POST /resource?from=xyz
```

Another brilliant idea is to use the Vary HTTP header.

```
 POST /resource
 Vary: xyz
```

Any problems with this approach ?

Answer (score 6):

Well, for one, "Vary" is a response header, so this is not so brilliant :-)

Answer (score 1):

If this is for security reasons, this is very bad security. Rather, use standard [HTTP authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) (or your custom authentication scheme) to pass credentials to the backend, and only *there*, based on credential/roles do whatever moderation/audit is required.

Comment: Yes, that is the proper way to distinguish users. Question, Jacques: why do you intend to do two different things through a single resource, anyway?